# how to execute multiple procedure script in sql-server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

Following is my select query written in *SQL SERVER*

```
select 'exec pr_tblmaster_split ''tblmaster_'+  Cast(year_id as nvarchar(4000)) +'''' as qry
from  tblmaster
group by year_id 
order by year_id asc
```

and this will return

```
qry
-------------------------------------
exec pr_tblmaster_split 'tblmaster_1'
exec pr_tblmaster_split 'tblmaster_2'
```

So my question is *How can i run the return query using a function/procedure?.*

---

Am trying to convert PostgreSQL to SQL Server, So

In PostgreSQL I can use *FOR LOOP*  like this

```
declare 
rw record;
begin
  for rw in 
         select 'select fn_tblmaster_spliting(''tblmaster_'||t.tbl||''');' crTables from (
         select distinct(year_id) tbl from tblmaster order by acyrid asc)t
   loop
         execute rw.crTables;
   end loop;
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the result in a `variable` and execute it through `sp_executesql`. Try this.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)=''
select @sql+= 'exec pr_tblmaster_split ''tblmaster_'+  Cast(year as nvarchar(4000)) +'''; ' 
from  tblmaster
group by year_id 
order by year_id asc

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I was also facing this problem and want to ask a new question, but in suggestion box I found this question and my problem is solved. thanks for grate answer